# Charts in Angular js with JSON Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-chart, chart.js

I am trying to implement chart representation in angular js.

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

I was able to implement simple charts but I have a below data to be represented. It is in JSON format. I need help on how to convert JSON to arrays to be represented as charts. Below is JSON

```
[{"value": {"DE":2,"NP":20,"BD":28,"TW":1},
  "end_time":"2016-07-05T07:00:00+0000"},
 {"value":{"DE":5,"NP":11,"BD":22,"BE":2,"FJ":2},
  "end_time":"2016-07-06T07:00:00+0000"},
 {"value":{"DE":5,"NP":24,"BD":29},
  "end_time":"2016-07-07T07:00:00+0000"}]
```

I am trying to convert it to the format

```
$scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July"];
$scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
$scope.data = [
[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
[28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];
```

I understand that I need to iterate over my JSON object and create arrays.

My question is I have different labels in each of the JSON object. How do I convert it create an array with all the labels in each of the value and still maintain the order of counts.Like below

```
$scope.labels = ["DE", "NP", "BD", "TW", "BE", "FJ"];
$scope.series = ["2016-07-05T07:00:00+0000","2016-07-06T07:00:00+0000","2016-07-07T07:00:00+0000"]
$scope.data = [ [2,20,28,1,0,0],
                [5,11,22,0,2,2],
                [5,24,29]
              ]
```

If this can be better achieved using different libraries or charts in angularjs please do suggest

Comment: So what is the problem? Should not be very difficult with the help of Array.prototype.forEach, Object.keys+forEach.

Comment: The problem is values in labels are different for each of the element in array. Like in first there is no BE and FJ label. I am very new to JavaScript too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you even attempted something? You didn't show any solution. Anyway, here's a possible implementation

```js
var source = [
  {"value": {"DE":2,"NP":20,"BD":28,"TW":1},
  "end_time":"2016-07-05T07:00:00+0000"},
  {"value":{"DE":5,"NP":11,"BD":22,"BE":2,"FJ":2},
  "end_time":"2016-07-06T07:00:00+0000"},
  {"value":{"DE":5,"NP":24,"BD":29},
  "end_time":"2016-07-07T07:00:00+0000"}
]
var $scope = {};
$scope.labels = [];
$scope.data = [];
$scope.series = [];


source.forEach(function(item){
  $scope.series.push(item.end_time)

  var values = []
  Object.keys(item.value).forEach(function(key) {
    if ($scope.labels.indexOf(key) === -1) {
     $scope.labels.push(key)
    }
    values.push(item.value[key])
  })
  $scope.data.push(values)
})
console.log($scope)
```

Comment: Definitely I have not written such a compact code, but for labels which are not present I need to have value 0, which is what my basic issue was. Can you help me in that. Thanks for the answer. I think I need to create a global list with all labels and then iterate. If key not present push zero.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Just use indexOf to check if not in list. Cheers